# reactNative.Share.open is undefined

Tags: javascript, java, swift, react-native, expo

I'm trying to use the share component with react native but I keep getting this error below. Any idea why ?

'_reactNative.Share.open is not a function. (In '_reactNative.Share.open({ url: uri })', '_reactNative.Share.open' is undefined)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because 'Share.open()' is now deprecated, use 'Share.share()' instead.